# How to set default download location in HTML?

Tags: php, html

How can i set the download location for a file. I have provide the FTP sever a link and i am providing a link to download it. Now i want it to specify a folder, so every one download and it went to that specific folder.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't. How could you be sure everyone would have such a folder, and if they didn't then what? Seems like a security problem if you could do this.

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible to set the download folder from the server side. The Peoples can choose a folder they want.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot control users computer or browser from your server script.

And if you are trying to do so please can you let us know what is the purpose behind doing this, so that we can find another way of doing it..

Thanks..